# Joe Blow bike pump failures in one way valve

Tags: pump

I used a bunch of Joe Blow bike pumps to pressurize water bottle rockets. Occasionally water squirted back into pump. After a few weeks of use, the one way valve failed. How can I fix this or prevent it from happening so often?

Comment: I would suggest that you find some sort of secondary one-way valve, and place that between the pump and the rocket.  Clearly, water leaking back into the pump is causing the damage.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because thos question is unrelated to bicycles.

Comment: Depending on how old the pump is and which joe blow it is, you may also want to use a rebuild kit on it.

Comment: @PeteH but it's about bike-related tools, and it's hard to imagine another SE where this would be on-topic. From that PoV, this is where the people most likely to know hang out. I think it's "technically out, but practically in", much as questions about workstands and torque wrenches are.

Comment: Was the backflow caused by water being sucked into the pump, or was it related to gravity?   Try putting the pump higher, on a stout wooden box and see if that helps.

Comment: Did the pump fail because it was wet inside and stayed wet?  Next time you might want to disassemble the pump after using it like this, and give all the parts a clean and lube.   Normally bike pumps are used for air, and any water content is minimal, so having water in the chamber may have rusted/siezed/upset parts.   Last resort is a rebuilt kit which will replace valves and seals, but if you're rusted the bore then it will need a hone to work right again.  Its worth fixing, don't be a lazy consumer and dump the old one!